# How to make ipython use Python 2.7 and not Python 3.4 (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I use `Ubuntu 14.04`. I had installed both `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.4` versions. I also had `ipython` installed (which was using `Python 2.7` by default). Later I installed `ipython3` using

```
sudo pip3 install ipython
```

and now I have `ipython3`. But when I only run `ipython`, it uses `Python 3.4` (as opposed to `2.7`). How to make default `ipython` use `Python 2.7`?

Answer (score 0):

open .bashrc and add in the bottom
alias ipython='/usr/local/bin/ipython2.7'

before adding check confirm name ipython name of version 2.7 in /usr/local/bin

Comment: which ipythons are available in /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: `ipython`, `ipython2` and `ipython3`. I changed your alias to `/usr/local/bin/ipython2` and restarted, but still not working.

Comment: Later I also uninstalled `ipython` as `sudo pip3 uninstall ipython3`. But ipython is still using `Python 3.4.*`.

Comment: in terminal just type  /usr/local/bin/ipython2  and see which ipython is opening.

Comment: ipython2 opens Python 2.7

Comment: then it will work and changes in .bashrc will reflect in next tab of terminal